# SQLite slower on Gingerbread compared to higher OS versions

Tags: android, sql, database, performance, sqlite

I have used an SQLite database in my Android app. The app uses an SQLite database. I have a standard **DBHelper** class which extends **SQLiteOpenHelper**.

Now, the database (and the app) performs as expected. An operation in my app uses around 100 SQLite queries to execute. It runs very fast (without any visible lag) in my **JellyBean** device. The problem arises when the app is run on a **Gingerbread** device. In the **Gingerbread** device, that same operation of 100 queries takes around 4 seconds!

So, I am looking for ways to make those DB queries run faster on **Gingerbread**. Any kind of help/tips would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Perform fewer queries. Doing 100 in rapid succession seems rather excessive. Beyond that, use Traceview to determine precisely where your time is being spent, check your query plan to ensure that you are using indexes correctly, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there some technical reason for the queries being slower on Gingerbread compared to the later versions?

Comment: Well, lots of things are slower on Gingerbread, including the devices themselves. Until you use Traceview to determine **precisely** where your time is being spent, all you will do is spin your wheels. The problem could literally be in SQLite itself (e.g., older version), or in populating the `Cursor` (e.g., Dalvik optimizations), or in rendering the results (e.g., hardware graphics acceleration for `Views`), or any number of other possibilities.